# Pom.xml conflict when integrating library module to another project module

Tags: java, android, maven, pom.xml

I am implementing a closed-source, custom module/SDK (intercom like),
using private repo on my own server depending on maven,
and have a small challenge in pom.xml file

**Issue description:**
Pom.xml file includes some dependencies that I used in my module when I integrate this library/SDK in any project,
somehow I have like a conflict between my dependencies and the project's dependencies.
For example :
I am using this dependency in my library module

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and the project I'm trying to integrate with using the latest version of the same library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

So, I have a compile-time error. I'm trying to solve the issue using `<dependencyManagement>` tag, but I've no luck in that.

Also, I can't specify what are the common dependencies between my library and the project which intended to use it.

**Question is:**
How to overcome the conflict issue.
I wanna my library module to use the 1.0.0 version of this dependency, and the other project uses the 1.2.0 version of it without conflicts.

**Edit-1**
Below is code used in my library to generate the pom.xml file :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId
            artifact androidJavadocsJar
            artifact androidSourcesJar
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${artifactId}-release.aar")
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                for(int i = 1 ; i < configurations.implementation.allDependencies.size() ; i++){
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId',
                            configurations.implementation.allDependencies[i].group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId',
                            configurations.implementation.allDependencies[i].name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version',
                            configurations.implementation.allDependencies[i].version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit-2** ( Attached pom.xml file )

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.constraintlayout</groupId>
      <artifactId>constraintlayout</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.legacy</groupId>
      <artifactId>legacy-support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.vectordrawable</groupId>
      <artifactId>vectordrawable-animated</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.material</groupId>
      <artifactId>material</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.exoplayer</groupId>
      <artifactId>exoplayer</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0` that will solve the problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise : Thanks for your replay , Actually the issue is a little bit complicated , the library / SDK  is already built in using specific dependancies  
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` is just an example , 
also , I don't know the dependancies that other developers will use in their projects and how they will differ from mine . (check my edit-2 for the for the full pom.xml file )

Comment: The simple answer to this: Based on the versions given it shows that those libraries do not follow semantical version. And I see no real solution either you decide to use version 1.2.0 furthermore the resulting version of the generated `botter` artifact which should be changed to an other version like `2.0.0` cause it's not compatible to the previous version which was `1.0.8` which is from semantical version point of view only a patch...but upgrading version 1.0.0 to 1.2.0 of a dependency which produces failures...

Comment: Issue will happen if the other project using higher version of exo-player in future (i.e. 2.11.6 ) , it will generate a conflict with my used version (2.11.5) .
Am I right?

Comment: How should I know? If so the version handling completely messed for exo-player ...as well...

Comment: Could you please help me to successfully handle the dependancies in the pom.xml?, I didn't get your solution.. If you can help will be great

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I will leave this Answer here, for anyone may face same issue.
I didn't change anything in the pom.xml file or in the project which integrate with the library.

I just realized that, I should change the theme for the google chip (which uses the material dependency) like below :

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
    <!-- Add the below line -->
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:textColor="@color/colorChatAccent"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:chipCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_5"
    app:chipStrokeColor="@color/colorChatAccent"
    app:chipStrokeWidth="@dimen/dimen_1" />
```

so, the issue wasn't in the pox.xml , it was in the Chip theme.